# node.js/expressJS 'Cannot Get /'

Tags: node.js, express

i'm using to render images in the index folder with .html

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port 3300;
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/index'));
app.listen(port,function() {
console.log("server listening on port " + port);
})
```

getting error cannot get /

Comment: Bcoz you have not added any get route in file @Revanth

Comment: In what url you are requesting for image???

Answer (score 0):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = 3300;
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/index'));
app.get('/',function(req,res){
     res.sendFile(__dirname + "file.html");
});
app.listen(port,function() {
console.log("server listening on port " + port);
})
```

** Keep html file and image file in index folder and then access it as given above.

In index/file.html

```
<img src='/img.png' />
```

Comment: By this i am able to view only the page but unable to load images that the page consists of

Comment: I have modified my answer. Kindly try this way.

Answer (score 0):

Create any folder, in my case, I have created **public** on the root and created index.html file in it.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = 3300;
console.log(__dirname);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.listen(port,function() {
console.log("server listening on port " + port);
})
```

Comment: I have done the same.Can you please check my code again because you wrote the same except 4 line.

Comment: have you added "=" after port ?